# Two-Dimen array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I created a two dimensional array and couldn't add values, I'm used to see so maybe it's not alike in Java.
The code is this way:

```
   int location[][] = new int[LEN][2];
   location[0][0] = 50;
   location[0][1] = 0;
   location[1][0] = 50;
   location[1][1] = 50;
```

There is no problem declaring but only assigning values into the array.
NOTE: LEN is bigger than 2 and I tried numeric value.

Comment: Code looks gud,whats the issue ?

Comment: There is no error in your code, provide a complete testable example that reproduces your problem

Comment: It gives an error which says " '[' expected ". Same with trying to assign numeric value to an object array (one dimen).

Comment: Are you sure that the error is for this part of the code?

Comment: You need to give us more code, the error isn't in the code you gave us. [Example](http://ideone.com/BBDWum)

Comment: start the array bracket '[' properly

Comment: Did you put the assignments `location[0][0] = 50;` .... in a method?

Comment: This does compile, see [Ideone](http://ideone.com/qlObiU), so you need to provide some more context or your actual code.

Comment: @NiksTyagi what do you mean?
+Here is the code example - http://pastebin.com/CEJp6G3j.
location is an array of block number and location itself (x, y).

Comment: Your error is on this line `Block block[] = new Block[LEN];`. The `[]` after `block` is a syntax error, it should be `Block[] block = new Block[LEN];`

Comment: @Danny that's no difference if I put it before.

Comment: @Danny No the first declaration is valid (though not recommended).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your pastebin, you have these element assignments outside a method body or other section of code that allows this kind of statement.

Probably you mean to have them in a constructor:

```
public window() {
    location[0][0] = 50;
    location[0][1] = 0;
    location[1][0] = 50;
    location[1][1] = 50;
}
```

<sub>Also note that in Java, the convention is that classes should start with an uppercase letter. `window` should be `Window`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have something like:

```
LEN = 50;
int location[][] = new int[LEN][2];
location[0][0] = 50;
location[0][1] = 0;
location[1][0] = 50;
location[1][1] = 50;
```

And that you tried:

```
location[50][0] = 24
```

This is going to fail, because in Java arrays are 0 indexed, meaning that you will get an array index out of bounds exception when using the index of 50.

To explain lets look at;

```
int[] ray = new int[50];
```

This has a size of 50, but when assiging or reading values must be read, assigned as 0-49.  This is 50 locations, but with a zero index.

If you can be more specific on the actual error you are seeing we can address that, but your code looks fine from what you've posted.

Edit:

I just checked and it looks like

int location[][] = new int[len][2]
won't work for 2d arrays, as per another answerer.

You need to change that to

int[][] location = new int[len][2];

Comment: "NOTE: LEN is bigger than 2 and I tried numeric value."  Only problem I see.

Comment: `location[50] = 24` is wrong, location is two dimensional.

Comment: Thanks ashot, typo =)

Comment: That would give an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception.  OP has a syntax error.

Comment: In the example I uploaded it says LEN is over 2. I know how to use arrays and indexes...

Comment: You also said "I tried the numeric value", presumably of len.

Comment: @NathanielWaggoner, not 50, at least 49 :) in `location[50][0] = 24`

Comment: Sorry for not explaining, I meant I tried to assign to a one-dimen array but it's not working - probably a problem in the context.

Comment: @NathanielWaggoner You should read all of the comments.  OP says: It gives an error which says " '[' expected

Comment: @mbroshi that wasn't there when I posted my answer.